# PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Issue: PayPal sends VERIFIED response but has FAILED status in IPN History. 404 Error

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

PayPal is sending the VERIFIED message to my IPN listener but my IPN History shows a FAILED status.  The IPN History also shows a 404 error.  The code I am using for my listener can be found here: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt.  I am testing this with sandbox.  How can I be receiving a VERIFIED response from Paypal but yet the IPN History shows a failed STATUS with a 404 error?  Shouldn't PayPal be sending an INVALID response since the IPN History status is failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VERIFIED has nothing to do with how the transactions appear in your ipn history. How you respond to the original ipn post is what determines what shows in your ipn history.

If your ipn history says it's receiving a 404 response, then you need to check your ipn script and stop sending a 404 response.

If it were any other error, since you are using PayPal's script, I would bet you didn't change the environment variable/the URLs to match your environments. With a 404 though, you're telling the client (paypal in this case)  that the page they want doesn't exist, even if you're still reading the data